# Convert a string based on hash values

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to write a method that takes in a string and a hash and "encodes" the string based on hash keys and values.

```
def encode(str,encoding)
end

str = "12#3"
encoding = {"1" => "one", "2"=> "two", "3"=> "three"}
```

I am expecting the output to be `"one two three"` any char in the string that is not a key in the hash is replaced with an empty string.

Right now my code looks like the following:

```
def encode(str, encoding)
  output = ""
  str.each_char do |ch|
    if encoding.has_key?(ch)
      output += encoding[ch]
    else
      output += ""
    end  
  end
  return output
end
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: WOW....nevermind this works...i had a typo in my code

Answer (score 2):

You can use use the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that uses a hash for substitutions, and a simple regex:

```
str = "12#3"
encoding = {"1"=>"one", "2"=>"two", "3"=>"three"}
```

First create a new hash that adds a space to each value in `encoding`:

```
adj_encoding = encoding.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = "#{v} " }
  #=> {"1"=>"one ", "2"=>"two ", "3"=>"three "}
```

Now perform the substitutions and strip off the extra space if one of the keys of `encoding` is the last character of `str`:

```
str.gsub(/./, adj_encoding).rstrip
  #=> "one two three"
```

Another example:

```
"1ab 2xx4cat".gsub(/./, adj_encoding).rstrip
  #=> "one two"
```

Ruby determines whether each character of `str` (the `/./` part) equals a key of `adj_encodeing`. If it does, she substitutes the key's value for the character; else she substitutes an empty string (`''`) for the character.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regular expression that matches your keys via [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
re = Regexp.union(encoding.keys)
#=> /1|2|3/
```

[`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) the string for occurrences of keys using that regular expression:

```
keys = str.scan(re)
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

fetch the corresponding values using [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
values = encoding.values_at(*keys)
#=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join) the array with a single space:

```
values.join(' ')
#=> "one two three"
```

As a "one-liner":

```
encoding.values_at(*str.scan(Regexp.union(encoding.keys))).join(' ')
#=> "one two three"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def encode(str, encoding)
  output = ""
  str.each_char do |ch|
    if encoding.has_key?(ch)
      output += encoding[ch] + " "
    else
      output += ""
    end  
  end
  return output.split.join(' ')
end

str = "12#3"
encoding = {"1" => "one", "2"=> "two", "3"=> "three"}

p encode(str, encoding) #=> "one two three"
```

Comment: Initializing an object (`output`) before iterating over something and appending items to the object is usually a code smell in Ruby, indicating an opportunity to use `map`, `reduce`, or `each_with_object`, e.g. `str.each_char.with_object([]) {|c, arr| arr << encoding[c] if encoding[c] }.join(' ')`

Comment: @Jordan I see, appreciate the tip.

Comment: Zack, @Jordan referred to "code smell". If you are not familiar with that expression, think "beached whale carcass", never, for example,
 "freshly-baked bread".

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting "one two three" you just need to add an space to your concat line and before return, add .lstrip to remove the first space.

Hint: You don't need the "else" concatenating an empty string. If the "#" don't match the encoding hash, it will be ignored.

Like this:

```
#str = "12#3"
#encoding = {"1" => "one", "2"=> "two", "3"=> "three"}

def encode(str, encoding)
  output = ""
  str.each_char do |ch|
    if encoding.has_key?(ch)
      output += " " + encoding[ch]
    end  
  end
  return output.lstrip
end

# Output: "one two three"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
encoding = {"1" => "one", "2"=> "two", "3"=> "three"}
str = "12#3"
str.chars.map{|x|encoding.fetch(x,nil)}.compact.join(' ')
```

Or two lines like this:

```
in_encoding_hash = -> x { encoding.has_key? x }
str.chars.grep(in_encoding_hash){|x|encoding[x]}.join(' ')
```